# Error LNK2005 in C++ project

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my function because of error LNK2005

```
void createNetwork(Link **linkTable, Router **router, Computer **computer) {

router = new Router*[5];
linkTable = new Link*[11];
computer = new Computer*[6];

//---------------------------------------------------------------
router[0] = NULL;
//---------------------------------------------------------------
router[1] = new Router(1);
router[1]->link = new Link*[4];
   ....
```

And error :

```
1>device.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl createNetwork(class Link * *,class Router      * *,class Computer * *)" (? createNetwork@@YAXPAPAVLink@@PAPAVRouter@@PAPAVComputer@@@Z) already defined in Computer.obj
1>Link.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl createNetwork(class Link * *,class Router * *,class Computer * *)" (?createNetwork@@YAXPAPAVLink@@PAPAVRouter@@PAPAVComputer@@@Z) already defined in Computer.obj
1>Packet.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl createNetwork(class Link * *,class Router * *,class Computer * *)" (?createNetwork@@YAXPAPAVLink@@PAPAVRouter@@PAPAVComputer@@@Z) already defined in Computer.obj
1>Queue.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl createNetwork(class Link * *,class Router * *,class Computer * *)" (?createNetwork@@YAXPAPAVLink@@PAPAVRouter@@PAPAVComputer@@@Z) already defined in Computer.obj
1>Router.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl createNetwork(class Link * *,class Router * *,class Computer * *)" (?createNetwork@@YAXPAPAVLink@@PAPAVRouter@@PAPAVComputer@@@Z) already defined in Computer.obj
1>sc.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl createNetwork(class Link * *,class Router * *,class Computer * *)" (?createNetwork@@YAXPAPAVLink@@PAPAVRouter@@PAPAVComputer@@@Z) already defined in Computer.obj
1>Time.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl createNetwork(class Link * *,class Router * *,class Computer * *)" (?createNetwork@@YAXPAPAVLink@@PAPAVRouter@@PAPAVComputer@@@Z) already defined in Computer.obj
1>E:\Dokumenty\Symulacja - Projekt\trunk\f4_sk_zelek_wit\Debug\f4_sk_zw.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I tried to fix it somehow but it didn't work. Can someone tell me what to do to fix it ? Thx :)

Comment: Post your code here instead of a screenshot (link).

Comment: Headers shouldn't typically contain function definitions for this reason. If more than one translation unit uses the header, both get the definition.

Comment: Of course .. Thx! Removing from .h file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to define a function in a header, mark it `inline` to allow a definition in each translation unit that includes the header.

Alternatively, move the definition into a source file, so it's only defined once.